# apache 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, http-status-code-403

Here is my .htaccess file's configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ backend/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this was working previously, but now when I deployed new version of it, its giving me the 403 error.

Its alow working locally but not on web.

http://www.pksupermarket.com

this is the domain.

Comment: This is most likely not related to your htaccess file.

Comment: This was likely something up with your host that has been rectified. The site is loading for me now. If it is not loading for you, try a third party test like downforeveryoneorjustme.com to eliminate your IP as the issue.

Comment: There is a potential problem with `mod_dir`, which could result in a 403 in some situations, since you are excluding directories from being rewritten. But as TunaMaxx points out, your site does appear to be working. Is this resolve now?

Comment: It was really strange, I was uploading the site using my Macbook, but after try about 3 times, I then uploaded it from windows, and It worked :-/ , also on my mac I'm unable to use Grunt, should I refresh my OS on mac???@LorenzMeyer

Comment: @w3d its resolved since I uploaded it from windows pc, thanks anyways.